# Java Stream filter a object list which does not contains a particular List of items as property

Tags: java, stream

I have a List of users.

```
public class User {
private String UserID;
private String departmentId;
private String email;
}
```

And I have a list of departmentIds

```
List<String> departmentIdList = Arrays.asList("111", "2222");
```

I need to filter the users with department Id **not** in the departmentIdList.
As per above example I need users whose department ID not equal to 111 or 2222.

Comment: What is your java version?

Comment: java version 1.8.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
users.stream().filter(
    u -> ! departmentIdList.contains(u.getDepartmentId())
).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Answer (score 8):

```
List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

List<String> departmentIdList = Arrays.asList("111", "2222");

List<User> usersNotInDepartments = users.stream()
        .filter(u -> !departmentIdList.contains(u.departmentId))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I would suggest that you make the departmentIdList to a Set data structure since it is more performant than Lists on lookup